# How to load HTML file as ohtml in url?

Tags: html, .htaccess

How to make .html extension file to be loaded as .ohtml in url
as example ..
this is the real url :
domain.com/file.html
i want it to be also loaded as this :
domain.com/file.ohtml
How is it possible through htaccess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it in your **.htaccess** file, and put it in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.ohtml$ $1.html [L,NC]
```